# redux Didnt Store in each state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

i called 3 actions in ComponentDidMount but the result are
saved inside of the last action that is called

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.token !== undefined) {
      this.props.getBillsRequest(this.props.auth.token)
      this.props.getProfile(this.props.auth.token)
      this.props.getInstallmentsRequest(this.props.auth.token)
      console.log(this.props)
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
    }
  }
```

expected ouput are

```
bills : {items: object}
profile: {user: object, detail: object}
installments: {0: object, 1:object , ...}
```

but instead i got

```
bills: {items: undefined}
profile: {user: undefined}
installments: {items: object, profile: object, biils: object}
```

Comment: Can you please first move all the logics out of reducer and as per standard keep it pure functions?

Comment: Don't post pictures; post a minimal code example. Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: ill move the logic in utils

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` for your fetch call instead of returning newstate directly after declaring the promise to be run, not doing this causes the newstate to return immediately hence it is in its initial state . But don't do this, your redux reducers should be pure.

You should not be making ajax calls in you reducers. See [Perform Ajax Fetch in a Redux Reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513318/perform-ajax-fetch-in-a-redux-reducer) for more details.

I recommend adapting some patterns for dealing with redux. I absolutely love the patterns outlined by Nir Kaufman see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUuic7mEs-s and https://github.com/isubasinghe/advanced-redux-patterns for its associated code